# retrieve data with toArray to use later in my code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, q, mongoskin

Background:

I'm trying to organize my code nicely & reuse it later, obviously i have no idea how! so i started experimenting with MongoClient & module.exports, I had no luck so i started adding mongoskin, then i realized node is an asynchronous programming language and maybe that's why i cant see the result in the console, so i got into promises and q, that didn't workout well since i couldn't get it to work right. then I found out there is something out there called winston this dude is suppose to help me log things out asynchronously, but it didnt.

**Question:**

so the question is how do i take data out of toArray and use it later in my code.

Bonus Question?

what is the best practice ? what would you think its a best way to organize things

connect.js:

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var Server = mongo.Server;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://xxx:xxx@xxx.mongolab.com:37617/xxx';
var q = require('q');
var winston = require('winston');

exports.jobs = function (){

    db = mongo.db(dbUrl, {native_parser:true});
    db.bind('jobs');

    q.Promise(
        function(){
        jobs = db.jobs.find().toArray(

            function (err, data){
                if(err) throw err;

                console.log(data);//I get data here
                return data;
            }

        );
        winston.log(data);//not working
        console.log(data);//not working
        }
    );
}
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
passport = require('passport-local'),
config = require('./config/config.json'),
Q = require('q');
console.log('\033[2J');
db = require('./models/connect');

var jobs = db.jobs(); //I want to have the data here in jobs var

var publicUser = require('./routes/publicUser'),
storeUser = require('./routes/storeUser'),
adminUser = require('./routes/adminUser');
app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use('/', publicUser);
app.use('/store', storeUser);
app.use('/adminO', adminUser);
//Load Statics
app.use(express.static('public'));  

app.listen(8080, function(){
console.log('listening......');
});
```

Comment: Asynchronous results are only usable from within the callback that signals the operation is complete or in a function you call from that callback.  That's how async programming works.

Answer (score 0):

For one, the variable `data` doesn't exist within the context of the two final log statements you're trying to use it in. Even if it did, you're not using the promise to gate those two functions. Lastly, promises operate on the premise that at some point it will either be resolved or rejected, neither of which is happening in your code. Here's one way you could implement your promise to get you the results you're expecting.

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var Server = mongo.Server;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://xxx:xxx@xxx.mongolab.com:37617/xxx';
var q = require('q');
var winston = require('winston');

exports.jobs = function (){

    db = mongo.db(dbUrl, {native_parser:true});
    db.bind('jobs');

    q.Promise( function(resolve, reject){
        jobs = db.jobs.find().toArray(

            function (err, data){
                if(err) reject(err);

                console.log(data);//I get data here
                resolve(data);
            }

        );
    }).then(function(data) {
        //Promise successfully resolved
        console.log(data);
    }, function(err) {
        //Promise was rejected
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```